Узнать лежат ли точки на маршруте Yamaps 2.1
Кто-нибудь знает, как без геокодера проверить лежат ли точки на маршруте?
Задача такая, есть маршрут какой-то, и массив точек(координат), нужно проверить лежит ли какая-то или несколько точек рядом с маршрутом и добавить их в маршрут заездом через них. Через геокодер сделал, нужно без него, в поддержке не отвечают как это сделать.
